# html page with one input "text". where does the focus go?

Tags: html, focus

because I am having some problems about when using onblur/onkeydown (for tabs) etcetera.

I 'd like to ask this question:

if I have a page with just one input text and I go there and I click the "tab" where is the focus going ? I'd like to know because I'd like to force the input text not to lose focus...

My page is like this:

```
<!docType>
<html>
   <body>
      <div><input type='text' /></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want it to start focused and stay focused forever?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, that's the idea. But my question is simpler where does the focus go if there is nothing else

Comment: It'll depend what browser you use. Probably it'll go to some browser option.

Comment: Depends on the browser probably.  Initially the input will get focused, but then it will start to focus browser controls too (such as the URL bar)

Comment: @ExplosionPills exactly that... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to focus specifically that text field than use `autofocus` attribute

```
<input type="text" autofocus />
```

Or if you want to map the tabs in a custom way use `tabindex` attribute

```
<a href="#" tabindex="2">Tab 2</a><br />
<a href="#" tabindex="1">Tab 1</a><br />
<a href="#" tabindex="3">Tab 3</a>
```

When there is 1 input text field and there's nothing after that, not even a link than probably the focus will go to the address bar of the browser, or probably it will move to add on bar if the user is having any browser add on, on the add-on bar

Comment: Alien thanks for that but I just want to know where the focus go if I press the tab. (since there is only one input text I just don't get where it goes)

Comment: @Zo72 Why don't you make a page and try :) I guess it probably should go to the address bar of the browser

Comment: it does... sorry I had not realized that... thanks for your help... I will mark you the right answer shortly.

Comment: As with my answer this will not work in Chrome as tabbing away from the very last element with tab index takes you to the URL bar. JavaScript would be needed to restore focus when the user then clicks back on the page rather than tabs back.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome when you tab away from an input and there are no other elements with tab index on the page the focus changes to the browser's URL bar. There probably won't be anything you can do to prevent this happening.

When you tab again it will return to that element - again provided it's the only element on the page with a tab index.

When you then *click* back onto the page (not the input) the focus isn't naturally restored to the input field (again, testing in Chrome here), so you may need to use JavaScript to force the focus upon the element.